# DXL script to check object contains two values in enum type attribute

Tags: ibm-doors

What is the DXL syntax to check whether DOORs object is having two enum values as Australia & India?

```
if ((isMember((current Object)."Country", "Australia")) && (isMember((current Object)."Country", "India")))
{
    addRequirement("Right-hand drive model needed")
}
OR
if (isMember(current Object)."Country", "Australia", "India")
{
    addRequirement("Right-hand drive model needed")
}
```

Please suggest the correct syntax as above two are not the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "undocumented perms list" shows that isMember only exists in the flavor `bool isMember (Attr__, string)`. So, the first syntax is correct.

[image]

Comment: But the first condition is not validating hence control is not going inside if loop. So any other alternate function to check whether enum attribute contains two values?

Comment: well, the if-statement works. Perhaps there is a problem with your loop? When you use "current Object)", are you aware that this refers to the currently marked object? If you are e.g. creating a DXL Layout column, you have to use the predefined variable "obj" instead of "current Object"